# Rosemary turning yellow

Tags: plant-health, herbs, rosemary

[image]

I've moved the rosemary to this pot a month ago, and where I live, the temperature is around 28-30 degrees celsius these days and usually i water them on a daily basis.
Everything looks just fine and even great, except for the color. Is it a soil problem? What nutrient is lacking?

Comment: Possibly just adaptation of new pot. Which dirt did you use? "One month ago" should be so short that extra nutrients should not be needed. Try to reduce water (e.g. 4 or 5 day a week).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as it is old leaves going yellow and there is new growth at the tops of the shoots, there is nothing to worry about. Rosemary likes full sun in summer (and more sun generates more essential oils) but it usually ends up looking a bit "weather beaten" by the end of the summer.

Comment: Thanks. But I wasn't sure about that because not the oldest leaves turned yellow  but the leaves that are not too old and not very new. And the overall color got brightened which was very dark green before.. Hmm... What you mean by "weather beaten" is the yellowish color?

Answer (score 1):

Rosemary is drought resistant, which means that it likes a bit less water than some other plants. Try watering only after you check by digging your finger into the soil and checking if it feels wet. You do not have to wait until it is bone-dry, just not really wet.  Also, rosemary is a Mediterranean type of plant and it might be somewhat dormant yet in those low temperatures.

Comment: 28-30 *celsius* isn't a low temperature. It's 80 to 85 F. Of course if the temperature was 28-30 *F*, the plant wouldn't be doing anything at all.

Comment: Oh, how silly of me!

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, the soil gets dry everyday in this season and sun and wind are very good at my terrace. That's why I water them everyday. Anyway, thanks for your advise! Everyone can be confused with Fahrenheit and Celsius. :)